# Displaying data from Firebase into Flutter error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to display the data from my firebase database into the Flutter app but keep getting error, does anyone know the reason and solution to it? I used to not get error when I added a check on checking if the snapshot has data, which I programmed to just display a Container() if there was no data. However, I realized that there was this error when I later tried adding a orderBy query, since I was suppose to get an error with a link to a a composite index to the database, but was not receiving it, so trying out many ways the whole day, I figured that there must be an error before it, so as soon as I removed the check if the snapshot has data, this error showed, so I have to fix this first in order to go to the orderBy part. Thank you! Here is the code

```
class ChatBody extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatScreenState createState() => ChatScreenState();
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatBody> {
  Stream messageStream;
  String chatRoomId;
  String myUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMyUserID().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        myUser = value;
        doThisOnLaunch(value);
      });
    });
  }

  //Gets my User ID
  _getMyUserID() async {
    final myUserId = await getUser();
    var myUserVar = myUserId;
    return myUserVar;
  }

  doThisOnLaunch(String myUserId) {
    getAndDisplayChats(myUserId);
  }

  // Function to get the messages from the firebase database and set it to the Stream to be able to build a real time StreamBuilder
  getAndDisplayChats(String myUserId) async {
    // print(myUserId);
    messageStream = await DatabaseMethods().getChatList(myUserId);
  }

  textTest() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: messageStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
            return chatList(
              ds["userName"],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  chatList(
    String userName,
  ) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(userName),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("HELOOO!"),
      ),
      body: textTest(),
    );
  }

//Top Nav Bar Actions Selection
  void choiceAction(String choice) {
    choice == Constants.AddContacts
        ? Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddFriendsPage(),
            ),
          )
        : choice == Constants.CreateGroup
            ? Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NewGroupPage(),
                ),
              )
            : print("no return");
  }
}
```

Here is the code for to fetch the data from Firebase

```
getChatList(String myUser) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRoom")
        .where("users", arrayContains: myUser)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

This is the error message

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>>#0d43b):
The getter 'docs' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: docs

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StreamBuilder<dynamic>
  file:///Users/vinpc/Development/projects/chat_app/lib/Screens/Home/Screens/TheChat/components/body.dart:62:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      ChatScreenState.textTest.<anonymous closure>
(package:chat_app/Screens/Home/Screens/TheChat/components/body.dart:66:36)
#2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:546:81)
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4553:5)
#9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4737:11)
#10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4548:5)
...     Normal element mounting (19 frames)
#29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#30     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
#31     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
...     Normal element mounting (105 frames)
#136    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3363:18)
#138    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1241:37)
#139    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1226:20)
#140    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2535:19)
#141    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1219:12)
#142    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:349:23)
#143    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1889:59)
#144    PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:912:15)
#145    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1889:14)
#146    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:338:5)
#147    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:422:5)
#148    RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:205:12)
#149    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#150    RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#151    _RenderSliverFractionalPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver_fill.dart:167:11)
#152    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#153    RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#154    RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1574:12)
#155    RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1483:20)
#156    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#157    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#158    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#159    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#160    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#161    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#162    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#163    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#164    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#165    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#166    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#167    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#168    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#169    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#170    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:937:7)
#171    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#172    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#173    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#174    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#175    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#176    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#177    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1369:11)
#178    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#179    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#180    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:937:7)
#181    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#182    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#183    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#184    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#185    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#186    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#187    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1369:11)
#188    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#189    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#190    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:937:7)
#191    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#192    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#193    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#194    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#195    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#196    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#197    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1369:11)
#198    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#199    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#200    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#201    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#202    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#203    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#204    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#205    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:54:11)
#206    RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:570:43)
#207    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#208    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#209    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#210    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#211    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#212    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#213    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#214    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#215    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#216    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#217    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#218    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#219    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3368:14)
#220    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#221    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#222    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#223    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:743:15)
#224    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1636:7)
#225    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:881:18)
#226    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:462:19)
#227    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:876:13)
#228    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
#229    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#230    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#231    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:998:5)
#235    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:163:10)
#236    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:259:5)
#237    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:126:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
═════════

Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'docs' was called on null.

Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'docs' was called on null.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [] for arrayContains

```
getChatList(String myUser) {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("chatRoom")
    .where("users", arrayContains: [myUser])
    .snapshots();
```

}

Comment: I think you mean `arrayContainsAny`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check to know if the snapshot has data before using the `.data` property which could be null.

Update your `textTest()` method to this:

```dart
 textTest() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: messageStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(); // Or CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
            return chatList(
              ds["userName"],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```